# How does the predicate 'append/3' work with an anonymous variable in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-anonymous-variable

How exactly does `append/3` work with an anonymous variable such as the one in the example below:

```
append(_,[b(F,ND,P)|Rest],Visited).
```

Couldn't we in fact just use [`append/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/2)?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `append/2` and `append/3` are very different. Usually, when people (typically erroneously) use `flatten/2`, they would be better off using `append/2`. As to your question: using an anonymous variable is semantically the same as using a variable not occurring elsewhere, so think about what `append(Xs, [b(F,ND,P)|Rest], Visited)` means, where `Xs` is such a variable: It means that `Visited` is a list comprised of a sublist `Xs`, followed by a sublist `[b(F,ND,P)|Rest]`. If we forget about `Xs` and `Rest`, it means that `b(F,ND,P)` occurs in `Visited`, i.e., `member(b(F,ND,P), Visited)`.

Comment: @mat That should be the answer and not a comment!

Comment: @mat. Please re-post your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal

```
..., append(_,[b(F,ND,P)|Rest],Visited).
```

reads:

> Somewhere in the list of `Visited` nodes, there is a `b(F, ND, P)` with subsequent nodes `Rest`.

Note that there might be more than one such node, so most probably there is a cut at some place or a `once/1`.

> Couldn't we in fact just use append/2?

Where did you dig out that skeleton - er - library predicate? But in fact, this may permit us to implement `append/3`:

```
myappend(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
   append([Xs,Ys], Zs).
```

So the intuition behind is that list `Xs` concatenated with list `Ys` is list `Zs`. From this declarative viewpoint, there are clearly no differences. Or are they?

At least procedurally, there **are** differences! For ...

```
?- append([], Ys, Zs), false.
   false.
```

... terminates, but ...

```
?- append([[], Ys], Zs), false.
   loops.
```

... loops! (In SWI and SICStus) Let's see the concrete answers produced (I'll use SICStus, because it prints variables more compactly, SWI uses hard-to-read variables like `_G1376`):

```
?- append([], Ys, Zs).
   Zs = Ys.
?- append([[], Ys], Zs).
   Ys = [], Zs = []
;  Ys = [_A], Zs = [_A]
;  Ys = [_A,_B], Zs = [_A,_B]
;  Ys = [_A,_B,_C], Zs = [_A,_B,_C]
; ... .
```

So `append/3` produced a single answer, whereas `append/2` seems to produce infinitely many. How can they be declaratively equivalent, or are they not?

#### Answers vs. solutions

First, let me point out that `Ys = [], Zs = []` above is a concrete solution. The next is the answer `Ys = [_A], Zs = [_A]` which contains infinitely many solutions. The `_A` stands here for infinitely many ground terms. So there is a way to collapse (or lift) infinitely many solutions into a single, elegant and finite answer.

Now, `append([], Ys, Zs)` went a step further, it collapsed all answers into a single one: `Ys = Zs`. But, is this right? This answer means that **any term** could be the `Ys`. In particular, say, `non_list` which is certainly not a list. Think of it:

```
?- append([a],nonlist,Zs).
   Zs = [a|nonlist].
```

So what `append/3` effectively did was to **overgeneralize** or to **lift** things too far. In fact, its definition is:

```
append([], Zs, Zs).
append([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]) :-
   append(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

The fact reads:

> The empty list appended with anything, really anything (including all Polish kings), is just that anything.

Clearly that fact states a bit too much. But it is this very overgeneralization that helped to improve termination properties! And, if we are a bit careful, this overgeneralization will never show. ((<sup><sub>Kind of a shady deal?</sub></sup>))

But then, Prolog enjoys many other properties - in particular the "single assignment" property of logic variables that mitigates this problem. The very same technique is used very often also for difference lists and  DCGs. If you use it consistently and wisely, it will improve performance and termination properties.